# Using regex to get link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, http, rest-client

I'm not sure how I'd select an image link with regex. I've tried for the past hour but no luck.

The response body I'm trying to select from: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/53971b49d783b90bf4b997b197ca3ee3/raw/c2a1f7c53ba89d67970ef8222bf5bf456c1679dd/gistfile1.txt

Trying to select "http://img-ineed.com/adsfasdf.jpg".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
string.match(/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I wouldn't of got that one! Quick question though, how would you just search jpg?